# Symfony Forms Invalidad Date

Tags: forms, symfony, datetime

Currently i'm working with PHP 5.6.2 in my laptop and the server has 5.5.0 both has configurated timezone to "America/Bogota"

the entity has a field like

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Column(name="start_date", type="datetime")
 * @NotNull()
 */
protected $startDate;
```

and the entity type is defined like

```
$builder
    ->add('startDate', 'date', array(
        'input'  => 'datetime',
        'widget' => 'single_text',
    ));
```

the data passed is formatted like `2015-01-15T06:11:37-0500` in my laptop that date is correct but in the server is **invalid**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are facing this problem, but I would advice you to specify the date format in the form like follows:

Also change date to datetime.

```
$builder
    ->add('startDate', 'datetime', array(
        'input'  => 'datetime',
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:ii:ss'
    ));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have included the format as you said and still keeps return invalid. Me neither quite understand that reason

Comment: I updated my answer, seems like you used the field type date instead of datetime.

Comment: sure, I just did the update on the server my code based

Comment: try datetime instead of date (altought it shouldn't work on the server either, but who knows)

Comment: thank you very much that was, but it's funny how was not happening before